# Get Id of Files record

Tags: apex, visualforce, contentversion

Is it possible to get the ID of a file that has been attached using Files. Below is a picture and when hovering over the download link, it display the id.

[image]

[image]

As seen above, the id of the attached image is in that link. Is it possible to obtain this link though Apex or Visualforce. I need the id of the image so I can display it on my Visualforce page.

**Edit**

The File is not static. Meaning there will be several attachments will be uploaded by users on the Account Object. I want to display the file on a Visualforce page. For this reason, I cannot directly copy and paste the id and I also cannot upload a static resource.

Comment: Is that file attached to a record like account or contact? You can directly copy the Id from the URL.

Comment: You're question is vague, please include a use case. Are you trying to get it in APEX? Or are you just trying to get the ID? Why do you need the ID? This seems like an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: If you want to show it in a Visualforce page, why not upload it as a Static Resource?

Comment: I have updated the question to describe my use case.

Comment: Are those attachment or salesforce files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your VF page controller just querry the contentDocumentLink or Attachments depending upon where your files are stored. Create a downloadable link and then display them in VF page.

Your controller code will look like.

```
public class AccountController {
    public Set<String> filesDownloadURL {set;get;}


    public AccountController(){
      String AccountId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

        //Assuming you have SF FILES
        List<ContentDocumentLink> cdLinks =[Select id,ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionID from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId=:AccountId];
        filesDownloadURL =new Set<String>();
        for(ContentDocumentLink cdl: cdLinks){
            filesDownloadURL.add(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() +'/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/'+cdl.ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionID);
        }

        // Assuming you have Attachments

        List<Attachment> attachmentLink = [Select id from Attachment where ParentId=:AccountId];

         for(Attachment att: attachmentLink){
            filesDownloadURL.add(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() +'/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+att.Id);
        }
    }

}
```

And your VF page code will be :

```
<apex:page controller="AccountController">
    <apex:repeat value="{!filesDownloadURL}" var="url" id="theRepeat">

         <img src="{!url}" width="100" height="100"/>
    </apex:repeat>

</apex:page>
```

Dont forget to pass "Id" as url param for concerned account

[image]

Comment: It works thank you. Is there some links you can provide me with to help me understand content version, document ect..?

Comment: I don't have any links as of now, might worth asking here.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_gaps_limitations_files_and_content.htm&type=5